# Javascript, fastest way to remove a class from `<body>`

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a body element on which I add a few classes. And I want to remove the `no-javascript` class from it, after it's being read by the browser.

```
   <body class="foo boo no-javascript bla">
   <script type="javascript">
      // remove no-javascript class here
   </script>
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Well, since extra spaces between don't matter, I'd say:

```
document.body.className = document.body.className.replace("no-javascript","");
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsbin.com/abixu5/2).

Comment: Falls over when you've got another class called "piano-javascript", for example.

Comment: @Tim - I agree, but look at the class name, this is a *very* specific use case.

Comment: Agreed. Just pointing out for anyone looking to apply this to the geenral case.

Comment: @Tim - Aye, fair point, for anyone ready this far, the more general use of the above would be: `document.body.className = " "+document.body.className+" ".replace(" no-javascript ","");`

Comment: ... except if "no-javascript" is at the start of the `className` string. The general case is covered by @Stephan Muller's answer.

Comment: @Tim - nope, look closer, I appended spaces to both sides.

Comment: @Nick: Oh, so you did. Now I look stupid. Although strictly speaking I think some whitespace characters other than spaces are allowed in class attributes, but that's really nitpicky.

Comment: \b should work to denote word boundaries

document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(/\bno\-javascript\b/gi,"")

edited to add code.

Comment: Oh man this code really screwed up all my piano-javascript classes!

Answer (score 32):

```
document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('no-javascript');
```

Comment: Since this is my preferred method, I'll explain. `document.querySelector` selects a specified element on the page using a CSS selector syntax, in this case, the `body`. Next the `classList` returns the classes associated with the element. Finally, `.remove` will remove any specified classes from the `classList`.

Answer (score 18):

There are no native javascript functions for this, but I always use the following code (borrowed from/inspired by [this snipplr](http://snipplr.com/view/3561/addclass-removeclass-hasclass/)

```
function removeClass(ele,cls) {
   var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)');
   ele.className = ele.className.replace(reg,' ');
}

removeClass(document.getElementById("body"), "no-javascript")
```

The regex does a better job than the `replace` functions mentioned in other answers, because it checks for the existence of that exact className and nothing more or less. A class named "piano-javascript" would stay intact with this version.

---

For [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=classlist) (including IE10 and up) you could also use:

```
document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('no-javascript');
```

Comment: One thing though: I'd lose the `hasClass()` check in `removeClass()`. It's redundant.

Answer (score 6):

```
document.body.className = '';
```

Comment: This will remove *all* classes, not just `no-javascript`

Comment: @El Ronnoco: I know. But it does remove the class, as asked. I know I'm being overly literal, but this *is* fastest :)

Comment: Point taken. Thinking like a true programmer! :)

Comment: I actually like this the best, I am using it to clear all class names before adding another on window width change.

Comment: The question clearly states that he wants to remove one of the many classes currently in body. I might be technically kind of ambiguous but this site is made for humans, not robots, and as a human I can clearly see his intent.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid all of that work simply by using

```
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
```

Since whatever you put inside of `noscript` tag will be shown if Javascript is turned off and nothing will be shown if JS is turned on.

Comment: but I want to show all the page even if js is disabled, I just need the class to hide certain elements with CSS