# Angular4 - How to remove a class that is injected by bootstrap from the document body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular, dom

I am using a 3rd party plugin (ngx-modialog) that has a plugin architecture and I am using its Bootstrap plugin. Unfortunately there is a [bug](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/ngx-modialog/issues/340) that after you use it to open a modal window, it does not remove a class from the body tag.

I can remove it myself after the user clicks the modal using jQuery:

```
jQuery('body').removeClass('modal-open');
```

But I would like to know how can I do the exact same as the above line in Angular?

I found I could do this to get a ref to the body:

```
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
```

I was hoping that might expose a **removeClass** method. There must be a simple way to do this, so I can abide by the rule of **NO JQUERY in Angular!** ;)

**NOTE**

I am NOT looking to use **[ng-class]** as I have nothing I can bind to in this scenario.

Comment: There is nothing special about removing a class from the body element. It's an element like any other element. There are a myriad answers about how to modify classes in JavaScript. There is nothing special with Angular. The body tag is outside Angular.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I was under the impression that Angular had its own way of grabbing elements from the dom using some typescript syntax?

Comment: Not when they are outside Angular. The only way this could apply would be if `AppComponent` had `'body'` as selector.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I see what you mean now by 'outside Angular'. Ok thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do that in Angular 4, you can use the [Renderer2 class](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)

Use the method: [removeClass(el: any, name: string): void](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#removeClass)

> **Renderer2** is an abstraction provided by Angular to manipulate elements of your app **without having to touch the DOM directly**

You can import Renderer2 like this:

```
import {Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
```

Inject it in the constructor of your component:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2){
}
```

**Remove a class:**

```
this.renderer.removeClass('body', 'modal-open');
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the 'body' is outside of the domain of Angular - Angular loads its component hierarchy inside it.

So therefore I just need to fall back to regular javascript to do this:

```
document.body.className = document.body.className.replace('modal-open','');
```

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397289/javascript-fastest-way-to-remove-a-class-from-body). No jQuery needed. But the accepted answer is the 'angular way' to do this, which is what I was after.